# Nginx Upload Module - upload_store fallback

Tags: nginx, upload

I have 2 drives om my server, hdd and ssd.

My goal is to upload all files to the ssd if possible, but if it's not writeable (for example, the drive is full) then it'll upload the file to the hdd.

I currently use [nginx's upload moudle](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/) with the following configuration:

```
location /upload {
    ...
    upload_store /var/tmp/fuploads;
}
```

Is there any way of having a fallback to the `upload_store` parameter?